# Filter Folder Name

Tags: excel, vba, select, keyword, directory

currently I am having a folder which contains many folders
Example : 

`A01
A02
A03
A04
B01
B02
B03`

I need only folder A01 to A04 comes out when I enter "A" in range B3, and so when I enter "B", only folder B01 to B03 will be shown. Can the folder name and folder path show in a checklist? And only the folder which is ticked will be process(I have other code to process the data)/ import after "OK" is pressed.

```
Sub FolderNames()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim xPath As String
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim fso As Object, j As Long, folder1 As Object
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Choose the folder"
    .Show
End With
On Error Resume Next
xPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1) & 
"\"
'Application.Workbooks.Add
Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet
xWs.Cells(1, 1).Value = xPath
xWs.Cells(2, 1).Resize(1, 2).Value = Array("Path", "Name")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder1 = fso.getFolder(xPath)
getSubFolder folder1
xWs.Cells(2, 1).Resize(1, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(194, 244, 238)
xWs.Cells(2, 1).Resize(1, 2).EntireColumn.AutoFit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub getSubFolder(ByRef prntfld As Object)
Dim SubFolder As Object
Dim subfld As Object
Dim xRow As Long
For Each SubFolder In prntfld.SubFolders
xRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
Cells(xRow, 1).Resize(1, 2).Value = Array(SubFolder.Path, SubFolder.Name)
Next SubFolder

End Sub
```

This is the code I have currently, it will show all the folder name and the folder path in cells but not checklist.
Any help and advise is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You are using Excel, did you know? What kind of check buttons do you want?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Actually I did not specify the types of the check button, as long as there is an option button to let me choose the folder that I want to process...

Comment: I already success to import the folder according to the keyword by adding
[If Left(UCase(SubFolder.Name), 5) = Range("E2") Then] code, but I still din't have idea how to add the option button....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the filter folder name part, I used

```
 For Each SubFolder In prntfld.SubFolders    
     If Left(UCase(Folder.Name), 5) = Range("E2") Then
     'your code here
     End If
Next SubFolder
```

For Each loop will loop through all the subfolders in the selected folder, and If...Then syntax helps to filter the folder according to the keyword, from the code above, the keyword should enter at the Range E2.

For the checklist part, I used

```
    counter = counter + 1
    Range("C" & counter).Value = "Yes"  'set the default value
        With Range("C" & counter).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="Yes,No"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With
```

Of course, this should put in a loop in order to ensure the number of counter will increase.
Hope this could helps someone that having the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

What about put some 'x' on the line you want to treat and then add a form (like circle or Square) and right click on it then "link to a macro" (In french "Affecter une macro").
This macro should have to parse the 'x' and do the job with the path.

If you really want something more visual, take a look at userform and more in treeview, they have CheckBoxes possible. (Add control Microsoft treeview Control, version Xx)

Comment: you're welcome and well done but you perhaps can says How you've done it ?